# NHibernate linq provider datediff

Tags: linq, nhibernate

Is where a way to write something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Finish{ get; set; }
}

Sessin.Query<Item>.Where( x => x.Start.AddHours( 3 ) > x.Finish );
```

Now i get an exception

> [NotSupportedException: System.DateTime AddHours(Double)]

Comment: Are you using NH3.3? and mapping by code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no easy way to make your LINQ query work. The problem with your scenario is that NHibernate doesn't know how to translate `DateTime.AddHours(double hours)` method. But can you use HQL to write a similar query? Apparently not. There is no standard HQL AddHours function. Therefore you have to register this new function. NHibernate uses dialects to translate between hql and vendor-specific SQL syntax. In order to do this you have to create a new dialect class deriving from an exising one and override RegisterFunctions method. 
But this solves only the first half of the problem. Next you have to show NHibernate how to use this function in LINQ. You have to "map" between `DateTime.AddHours(double hours)` method and the previosly registered custom hql function. NHibernate uses a registry for this purpose. You will have to extend the default linq-to-hql registry.

I will show an example that worked with NHibernate 3.3

Create a new dialect class (my example uses the predefined MsSql2008Dialect)

```
    public class EnhancedMsSql2008Dialect : MsSql2008Dialect
    {
        protected override void RegisterFunctions() {
            base.RegisterFunctions();
            RegisterFunction("add_hours", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.DateTime, "dateadd(hour, ?1, ?2)"));
        }
    }
```

Create a new LINQ-to-HQL generator class that knows how to translate AddHours method

```
    using NHibernate.Linq.Functions;
    using NHibernate.Linq;
    using NHibernate.Hql.Ast;

    public class DateTimeMethodsHqlGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
    {
        public DateTimeMethodsHqlGenerator() {
            SupportedMethods = new[] {
                ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition((DateTime x) => x.AddHours(1))
            };
        }

        public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor) {
            return treeBuilder.MethodCall("add_hours", visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(), visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression());
        }
    }
```

Extend the default LINQ-to-HQL registry class

```
    public class EnhancedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
    {
        public EnhancedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry() : base() {
            //
            RegisterGenerator(ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition((DateTime x) => x.AddHours(1)), new DateTimeMethodsHqlGenerator());
        }
    }
```

Configure

```
    cfg.DataBaseIntegration(c => {
        c.Dialect<EnhancedMsSql2008Dialect>();
    });
    cfg.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<EnhancedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();
```

Comment: Pretty much same answer as mine and answered five mins later :)

Comment: didn't press the "show new answer" while I was editing, left my solution since yours didn't have the custom dialect before editing

Comment: Thank you for answer and good description of situation. BTW using Merge method in DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry looks a bit prettier :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using NH 3.3 and Loquacious configuration then you can do something like this..

Add the `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry` to the configuration:-

```
        var configure = new Configuration()
            .DataBaseIntegration(x => {
                x.Dialect<CustomDialect>();
                x.ConnectionStringName = "db";
             })
            .LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
            .CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>();
```

and add the following three classes:-

```
public class MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
    {
        this.Merge(new AddHoursGenerator());
    }
}

public class AddHoursGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public AddHoursGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[] {
        ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<DateTime?>(d =>      
                d.Value.AddHours((double)0))
          };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method,
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject,
        ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
        HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.MethodCall("AddHours",
                visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression(),
                visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression()
            );
    }
}

public class CustomDialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
    public CustomDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction(
             "AddHours",
             new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                  NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
                  "dateadd(hh,?2,?1)"
                  )
             );
    }
}
```

I have based this on this [blog post](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html) by fabio.

You can now use your code as is:-

```
Session.Query<Item>.Where( x => x.Start.AddHours( 3 ) > x.Finish );
```

This is also possible in 3.2 but the `public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(..)` parameters are slightly different...

Comment: Thank you for solution! I'm sorry i accepted another answer because it has good descritpion of what happening and why.

Comment: Don't worry I am not too bothered although some bit of me feels the other answer should be removed, you win some you lose some.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, does datetime subtract two dates? if its just hours then use `AddHours(-4)`