# Given a DateTime, how to Call .ToUniversalTime when using LINQ to NHibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a method which returns all the events based on an EventTypeID:

```
 public IList<Event> FindAll(int eventTypeId, DateTime? modifiedSince)
        {
            IQueryable<Event> query = this.SessionFactory.Session.Query<Event>().Where(e => e.EventType.Id == eventTypeId);

            if (modifiedSince.HasValue)
            {
                // .ToUniversalTime() call throws NotSupportedException
                query = query.Where(et => et.ModifiedDate.ToUniversalTime() >= modifiedSince.Value);
            }

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

How to call .ToUniversalTime() method for each record as shown above?

I ideally don't want to call .ToList() first then filter.

If it's not supported at all, how can I extend the LINQ to NHibernate to support this specific feature?

Comment: Instead of attempting to modify every row in the table ToUniversalTime, could you change modifiedSince to a time that is correctly relative to the database entries?

Answer (score 1):

This may be somewhat difficult to resolve, because I expect that the rows of data you're retrieving include times in different time zones.

This problem occurs because your et.ModifiedDate.ToUniversalTime() call is passed in the query and the target of the query does not support that operation (which is why you see this at runtime instead of compile-time).

To circumvent this, one typically performs the calculation required outside of the query block and passes in that value.

You will have to consider another way to perform your test.

Comment: Thanks but I can't calculate outside of the query block, the calculation has to run for every row in the table which is participating in that query.

Comment: In that case, about the only thing I can come up with is to remove the filter from your query so that it returns all rows, and then filter the resultset locally.

Comment: Doesn't this approach work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604941/nhibernate-linq-provider-datediff